# When should a Logger flush?

Tags: c++, c++11, logging

I want to know when, or how often should a Logging class flush its stream - and why? Should it flush after every log, or wait for the stream buffer to fill and then flush, or is it somewhere in between?

To further illustrate my question:

My logging class holds a reference to some `std::ostream stream` and uses `operator<<` for input. I am able to flush after every line of input, let's say by using `std::endl;` - but i don't, instead i `use stream << "\n"` to just force a newline. I let flush happen when the stream buffer is full or on stream /logger destruction.

Comment: A reasonable approach would be to flush based on log message level, that is something like fatal / error messages should be delivered immediately while the less critical can dwell in the buffer for a bit.

Comment: @Ron In C++ a stream is a very well defined concept by the standard. This question is very clear to C++ programmers.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Which stream did you have in mind? `std::ostream`, `std::stringstream`, `std::fstream` or perhaps the `ios_base` class as a starting point?. At the [time of asking](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49348415/revisions) none of that was in the question.

Comment: Question first posed was without the part "To further illustrate my question:" . I have edited it on Ron's advice but haven't credited his comment. My bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As often as possible, so that no entries are lost upon a crash, and also to have better real-time information while the program is running.

As rarely as possible to avoid overhead of writing to a file.

These requirements conflict, so you need to find a balance that fits your needs.

You might want to consider that some log messages may be less important than others, and you may use this to affect your flushing policy.

You can use signal handlers (or similar OS specific techniques) to flush the buffer right before a crash. Note that flushing a `std::stream` is technically something you're not allowed to do in a signal handler (although that might depend in its implementation), but it *might* work and that's usually better than just crashing.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: Curious anecdote: I worked on a cross-platform server (Linux/Windows) and we used logging infrastructure from the POCO C++ libraries. We had horrible logging performance on Windows while Linux performance was generally acceptable. Looking at the POCO source code, I discovered that the Linux implementation basically did (IIRC) an `fwrite`+`fflush`, which flushes the log *to the OS*, but on Windows it did `WriteFile`+`FlushFileBuffers`, where the former already writes everything to OS, and the latter then flushes *to disk*, even safer but vastly slower (it corresponds to POSIX's `fsync`).

Answer (score 3):

In C++ the iostreams library has 2 classes for logging.
Both are bound to `stderr`.

`cerr` - flushes after each input is formatted, which means after every call.

`clog` - flushes when buffer is filled or called manually (example: `endl` or `flush()`).

The thinking is that, you want errors to be output ASAP.
But logging can be output in batches.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends.** Though logging is often narrowed down to denote some kinds of error-related messaging mechanism, it is not always tied with errors. In contrast, sometimes it is even explicitly separated with errors (e.g. `clog` vs. `cerr`). Another example is [*tracing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_(software)) in general. So it is up to you, the designer of the logging system, to decide which integrity level you want to achieve with specific logging.

Stream-based logging can be a simple way to report errors. It is not the feature of last sorts, but it is unwise to be depended as the *only* way to record *fatal error*s. Just better than nothing (particularly in cases where portability is emphasized)... when you *have to* rely on this way, flush it ASAP.